# R: Add column to data frame with values in an indexed vector, including NAs

Tags: r, dataframe, vector, indexing

I have a data frame with a value column including NAs, like this one:

```
> set.seed(1)
> mydf <- data.frame(name=LETTERS[1:10], col1=rnorm(10, 2, 1))
> mydf
   name     col1
1     A 1.373546
2     B 2.183643
3     C 1.164371
4     D 3.595281
5     E 2.329508
6     F 1.179532
7     G 2.487429
8     H 2.738325
9     I 2.575781
10    J 1.694612
```

Now I want to add another column that I have stored in a numeric vector. This vector tells me the index (row) where each value should be inserted, but does not include NAs for the missing indexes:

```
> a <- rnorm(6,5,2)
> names(a) <- c(2,4,5,7,8,10)
> a
        2         4         5         7         8        10 
8.0235623 5.7796865 3.7575188 0.5706002 7.2498618 4.9101328
```

I want to add `a` as a column to `mydf` following the indexes (`a` names), so that `mydf` looks like this:

```
> mydf
   name     col1      col1
1     A 1.373546        NA
2     B 2.183643 8.0235623
3     C 1.164371        NA
4     D 3.595281 5.7796865
5     E 2.329508 3.7575188
6     F 1.179532        NA
7     G 2.487429 0.5706002
8     H 2.738325 7.2498618
9     I 2.575781        NA
10    J 1.694612 4.9101328
```

This should be really simple, but cannot get my head around it. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should give you your desired result.

```
merge(mydf, a, by = 'row.names', all.x = TRUE)[,-1]
```

Comment: Alright! I was thinking about `merge`, but I didn't know I could do it by `row.name`!

Comment: I don't know why, but on my actual long data frame, I lose the correct indexing, the data frame somehow gets shuffled

Comment: Ok but in the column Row.names I keep the original indexing if I don't do [,-1]...

Answer (score 1):

We can initialise the new column (`col2`) with `NA` and then extract the specific index from the `names` of `a` and replace it with value of `a`.

```
mydf$col2 <- NA
mydf$col2[as.numeric(names(a))] <- a
mydf

#   name     col1      col2
#1     A 1.373546        NA
#2     B 2.183643 8.0235623
#3     C 1.164371        NA
#4     D 3.595281 5.7796865
#5     E 2.329508 3.7575188
#6     F 1.179532        NA
#7     G 2.487429 0.5706002
#8     H 2.738325 7.2498618
#9     I 2.575781        NA
#10    J 1.694612 4.9101328
```

---

**Update**

As per OP's comment if the row indexes start at some arbitrary number then the above does not give the correct answer. In that case, we need to `match` the `names` of `a` with the `rownames` of `mydf` and assign the respective values to `col2`.

```
 mydf$col2 <- NA
 mydf$col2[match(names(a), rownames(mydf))] <- a
```

Comment: This does not work if `mydf` row indexes start at say 55 instead of at 1...

Comment: @DaniCee how can I reproduce the issue?

Comment: Try, for example `row.names(mydf) <- 61:70` and `names(a) <- c(62,64,65,67,68,70)` so the indexing starts at 61 instead of at 1